# Can a limit have the same value while not being differentiable

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjBAW.jpg)So I'm working out a problem and I end up with both sided limits equaling to one for differentiability, while the limits for whether its continuous or not are not the same. Meaning it's not continuous, but it resulted in the same value for differentiability. 
I know something cannot be differentiable if it is not continuous, but is there a scenario where the you result in the same value for in a $f'(x)$ limit, while getting two different limits for $f(x)$? 
[attached image is my work for the question of whether $\frac{1}{6}x^2 + 1$ and $x+1$ are differentiable at $x=3$. The two equations have been proven to not be continuous at $x=3$.]

Edit : I'm not allowed to post images directly yet. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjBAW.jpg

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: I was wondering if it is plausible to have something appear differentiable but in fact not be because it is not continuous. Like if you only worked with the question of if something is differentiable without checking if its continuous.

Comment: Ok, I can answer that.

Comment: I don't see the attached image.

Comment: Image updated, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways something can be discontinuous: (1) the right and left limits exist, but disagree, (2) the right and left limits exist, agree, but aren't equal to the value of the function at the point, (3) either the right or the left limit does not exist.

Let $f(x)$ a function and suppose $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ existed was was equal to $L$. Then $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) - f(x_0) = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{x-x_0}{x-x_0} (f(x) - f(x_0)) = \lim_{x \to x_0} (x-x_0) \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \lim_{x \to x_0} (x-x_0) \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = 0 \cdot L = 0$. Thus $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) - f(x_0) =0 $, so $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$.

So we see that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, and in particular you see that it is impossible for it to be discontinuous in any of the 3 possible ways.

So if $f$ "appears" differentiable at $x_0$, it must be continuous at $x_0$. This is what we mean when we say that differentiability implies continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Your question (in attached image) clearly has a typo. The definition of your function as per your image is as follows $$g(x) =\begin{cases}
2\sqrt{x}, &0\leq x\leq 1\\
x+1, &1\leq x\leq 3\\
\dfrac{x^2}{6}+1, &3\leq x
\end{cases} $$ When we define a function via multiple formulas for different range of values of the variable then we need to ensure that the range of values of $x$ are indeed different. Here it is not the case as $x=1$ is common to both $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $1\leq x\leq 3$ and $x=3$ is common to both $1\leq x\leq 3$ and $3\leq x$. In case there are point common in both ranges we must ensure that the values of function at those points are same via both the formulas (because obviously a function has a single value at a point).

The problem occurs here not at $x=1$ and both $2\sqrt{x}=2$ and $x+1=2$ but at $x=3$ where $x+1=4$ and $x^2/6+1=5/2$. So the function is not defined properly.

Check your book. Probably you will have the last range as $3<x$ and based on it try to find $g(3)$. The function will then turn out to be discontinuous at $x=3$ as well as not differentiable at $x=3$. This is expected as "differentiability implies continuity".